# c# winforms app updating all the records in ms access

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-access-2010

As i update any record, the whole table got updated with same record (row), I am trying the following code. I had also tried concatenation but someone told me about sql injection.

```
con.Open();
try
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE emptable 
                        SET EmpName=@EmpName, Age=@Age ,Mobile=@Mobile,  
                            Designation=@Designation ,Salary=@Salary ,  
                            joiningDate=@joiningDate ,Address=@Address,  
                            AccountNo=@AccountNo,  
                            AccountHoldersName=@AccountHoldersName,  
                            BankName=@BankName,IFSC=@IFSC, 
                            EmpCode=@EmpCode,UINPANNO=@UINPANNO,
                            Whatsapp=@Whatsapp,FathersName=@FathersName,
                            MaritalStatus=@MaritalStatus,Email=@Email 
                     WHERE Mobile= Mobile";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", EmpNametxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Agetxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", Mobiletxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", Designationcmbbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", Salarytxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JoiningDate", dTP1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Addresstxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNo", Accounttxtbx.Text);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountHoldersName", Holderstxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankName", Banktxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IFSC", Ifsctxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpCode", EmpCodetxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UINPANNO", Uptxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Whatsapp", Whatsapptxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FathersName", Fatherstxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", MStatuscmbbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Emailtxtbx.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("record update");

    //refresh or update table 
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = con;
    string query = "select * from emptable";
    cmd1.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error   " + ex);
}

//  Clear();
con.Close();
```

Comment: `WHERE Mobile= Mobile` should be replaced by `WHERE Mobile= @Mobile`

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do but current problem cause by "typographical error" - `WHERE Mobile= Mobile";` is always true and hence all record match that condition.

Comment: And after fixing the problem with the WHERE typo you will have also a logical error here. You use the Mobile value two times, once to update the field and once to search for it in the WHERE clause, now you need a separate parameter if the two values are different. (old-new)

Comment: after changing condition `Where Mobile = @Mobile,` it updated all records for that column. like all the employees name become same as i update the name .means it works on the  entire column beside making updation for the single row ...thanks for giving me your valuable time but i m still in trouble please help me  ,@ Chetan Ranpariya, @ Alexei Levenkov  , @ Steve

Comment: Did you add another parameter for the added _WHERE Mobile = @Mobile_?. In OleDb parameters are positional, they are not recognized by their name (@xxx) so if you have 18 parameters placeholders, you need to add 18 parameters in the exact order in which the placeholders appear in the sql text.

Comment: Thanks to all now its working fine.....with a minor problem mobile cant be edited

Answer (score 0):

Problem is a just a typo here `WHERE Mobile= Mobile`.
It should be `WHERE Mobile=@Mobile`, so `Mobile` is passed as parameter and not as table value. In that case infact condition is always true and so every single record gets updated!

About concatenation: never ever use concatenation to build queries!
Not only you're messing up with your code and you're ready to heavy headaches to debug if something goes wrong, but as someone told you you're risking SQL injection too!

Comment: after changing condition Where Mobile = @Mobile, it updated all records for that column. like all the employees name become same as i update the name .means it works on the entire column beside making updation for the single row ...thanks for giving me your valuable time but i m still in trouble please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Mobile= @Mobile
```

about the Sql injection you can use application | Three Tire Architecture | by connecting over a Data Access Layer and using stored procedures then encrypt your Business Layer or Controller ... But MS Access not support stored procedure you can use MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code, the where-condition parameter in.accb files should not have a similar value. You need to clear the privos value in your accdb file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).